# Using Broadcast Receiver with Direct Boot in Android Nougat (7.0)

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver, android-7.0-nougat

I am working with the new DirectBoot feature in Android 7.0 and I am trying to determine when the phone is still locked after a restart and in Direct Boot mode. To do this, I have implemented a BroadcastReceiver which I defined in the Manifest.

My understanding is that when a phone is restarted, it sends out an ACTION_LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast when it finishes booting but prior to the user entering their PIN. When the PIN is entered and phone becomes unlocked, an ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED broadcast is sent. My Receiver works fine if I define its intent-filter to be ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED, but as soon as I add LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED, I get Fatal error messages like this upon restarting the phone saying it couldn't instantiate my receiver:

```
01-06 07:25:30.917 3872-3872/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                             Process: com.example.nougatencryptiontest, PID: 3872
                                             java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate receiver com.example.nougatencryptiontest.MyReceiver: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.nougatencryptiontest.MyReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.nougatencryptiontest-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.nougatencryptiontest-1/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3021)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18(ActivityThread.java)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1561)
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                                              Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.example.nougatencryptiontest.MyReceiver" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.example.nougatencryptiontest-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/data/app/com.example.nougatencryptiontest-1/lib/arm64, /system/lib64, /vendor/lib64]]
                                                 at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
                                                 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:380)
                                                 at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:312)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.handleReceiver(ActivityThread.java:3016)
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap18(ActivityThread.java) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1561) 
                                                 at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                                                 at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                                                 at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                                                 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                                                 at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

I'm not sure why this DexPathList issue occurs only when I change my Receiver's intent-filter from BOOT_COMPLETED to LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED. Below is my Manifest that does not work (however, if I change intent-filter to just be BOOT_COMPLETED, application doesn't crash and receiver works perfectly fine!):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
package="com.example.nougatencryptiontest">

<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED"/>


<application

    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:directBootAware="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">


    <receiver android:name=".MyReceiver"
        android:exported="true"
        android:directBootAware="true">
        <!-- Listening the BOOT_COMPLETED action for legacy pre-N devices -->
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.LOCKED_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>


    <activity android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:directBootAware="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>

</application>
```

Any advice or pointers would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Just an idea : check if the app is installed in on the external storage or in the internal ? (it can not work when installed on the external)

Comment: An other idea, is your receiver using other components of your app that may still be encrypted (like : is directBoot ok with native libs) ?

Comment: Have you found a solution?  I am facing the same issue.